# Direction of shiva lingam

Tags: shiva, shiva-purana, shiva-lingam, shakti, jyotirlinga

I've went to many Lord Shiva temples and seen the lingam in different directions.

In some temples, the direction is like this:

[image]

And in some temples, the direction is like this:

[image]

Why is there a difference and can someone tell me the reason behind it?
Any significance?

In that case, how should the Lord Shiva Lingam be kept in the home? Like which direction?

Comment: Yoni or Lingapeetha (base) should face North.

Comment: Could you please tell me which portion is Yoni/Lingapeetha?

Comment: In few temples, the Yoni doesn't face North. So, I wanted to clarify what do you mean by Yoni

Comment: The Protruding portion. It has to face North as per scriptures. In second pic, yoni faces right side which is North.

Comment: Ok, so there are no lingams where the Yoni will face any other position other than North?

Comment: Would be really beneficial if you could tell me why the Yoni should always face the North direction?